# np.tril does not make things exactly 0

Tags: python, numpy

```py
import numpy as np

def foo (A):    
    (m,n) = A.shape
    if m < n:
        return -1,0,0;
    
    D = A.copy()
    U = []
    for i in range(n-2):
        I = np.identity(m-i-1)
        e = I[:,0]
        a = D[i+1:m,i]
        
        u = a - np.linalg.norm(a)*e
        u = u/np.linalg.norm(u)
        
        U.append(u)
        
        for j in range(i,n):
            D[i+1:m,j] -= 2*np.dot(u,D[i+1:m,j])*u
            
    return np.tril(D)
```

In this code, for example when I print out what foo returns to a random 4x4 matrix, for some reason the upper triangle that was supposed to be exactly 0 are not made exactly 0, but instead shows 0.000000e+00 in the console. Is there a reason why the compiler failed to clear out the 0's? Also the 0's could be easily cleared for if I just apply np.tril a random matrix directly.

Comment: not really, because I thought numpy.tril clears out the entries to be exactly 0

Comment: Why do you think the value isn't exactly zero? Did you try `... == 0`? Note that when printing arrays, numpy tries to print all values with the same number of digits and with either all or none using scientific notation.

Comment: Note that the default implementation of Python is CPython which is *not* a compiler but an interpreter. Cython is a compiler. PyPy is a JIT compiler. An interpreter is generally much slower than a compiler (but often less flexible too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason the upper triangle that was supposed to be exactly 0 are not made exactly 0

And it *is* exactly set to 0. You can test that with:

```
res = foo(A)
print(res[0,0] == 1)
print(res[0,1] == 0)
print(res[0,2] == 0)
print(res[1,2] == 0)
```

which shows:

```
True
True
True
True
```

You might think Numpy is rounding the values internally or make a weak check, but this is not true too because `print(res[0,0] == 1.000000000000001)` print `False` and the same apply for `print(res[0,1] == 1e-320)`. Thus, the problem as nothing to do with values not being equal to exactly 0. The issue comes from *misleading printed results*.

> but instead shows 0.000000e+00 in the console

If you print `res`, you will see that:

```
array([[1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [8.06225775e+00, 9.42663983e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.77635684e-15, 3.72104204e-01, 7.44208408e-01]])
```

But if you print `res[0,:]`, you will get that:

```
array([1., 0., 0.])
```

The fact you get `0.00000000e+00` in the first case and `0.` in the second just comes from the matrix printing algorithm of Numpy: the precision of the printed numbers is adapted regarding all the values in the array. The accuracy of the number is left unchanged. More specifically, Numpy check the other numbers in the same line and the same columns to perform a pretty printing of the values. If you do not trust this, you can just reset the values of `res` yourself using `res[2,:]` (which left the first line unchanged) and print it. You will get this result:

```
array([[1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [8.06225775, 9.42663983, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```